# Getting PKIX path building failed, ValidatorException while requesting a url

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am using REST Assured, but when I try to send the request I am getting the below error:-
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

```
    public SpreadSheetServiceCall() {
       RestAssured.baseURI = "https://www.google.com/place?multiSelect=";
}

    public Response getSpreadSheet() {
    return RestAssured.given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).when().get();
    }
```

Console Error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error
    at sun.security.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:557)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1974)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:492)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:441)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$request$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendHttpRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1396)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1596)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:160)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:244)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at uk.co.tui.cdaf.backend.services.SpreadSheetServiceCall.getSpreadSheet(SpreadSheetServiceCall.java:46)
    at uk.co.tui.cdaf.backend.stepdefs.SpreadSheetStepDefs.a_cusotmer_needs_to_verify_available_reposnse(SpreadSheetStepDefs.java:36)
    at ✽.a cusotmer needs to verify available reposnse(file:/C:/CDAF_BDDProject/phoenix-apps/cdaf/resources/features/SamplePageNavigations.feature:54)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SunTls12RsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.<init>(KeyGenerator.java:169)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getKeyGenerator(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:557)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1974)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:492)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:441)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$request$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendHttpRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1396)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1596)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:160)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:244)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at uk.co.tui.cdaf.backend.services.SpreadSheetServiceCall.getSpreadSheet(SpreadSheetServiceCall.java:46)
    at uk.co.tui.cdaf.backend.stepdefs.SpreadSheetStepDefs.a_cusotmer_needs_to_verify_available_reposnse(SpreadSheetStepDefs.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:26)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:20)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:57)
    at cucumber.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:50)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:63)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:49)
    at cucumber.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:43)
    at cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:45)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$1.run(Runtime.java:82)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:217)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:79)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:26)
    at cuc
```

umber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:8)

Comment: `NoSuchAlgorithm` suggests your cryptoprovider list is screwed up. At or near the point of creating the session do `for(java.security.Provider p : java.security.Security.getProviders() ) System.out.println (p.getName()); // or other suitable output` and see if SunJCE is in the list and where.

Comment: below is the list which I got
SUN
SunRsaSign
SunEC
SunJSSE
SunJCE
SunJGSS
SunSASL
XMLDSig
SunPCSC
SunMSCAPI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running into an SSL `SunCertPathBuilderException` problem which most probably comes because you are missing required and/or valid certificates in your JVM's keystore which runs your Rest Assured test.

Either you dig further into this certificate chain issue or if it is appropriate for you, use a [relaxed HTTPS validation](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#ssl) with `useRelaxedHTTPSValidation()`.

In your example put it in this way:

```
RestAssured.given().useRelaxedHTTPSValidation().contentType(ContentType.JSON).when().get()
```

I've included your call in a working test in my example project and as you can see it responds (HTTP 403, probably because the API is secured) fine, especially without any `SunCertPathBuilderException`:

https://github.com/mle-enso/stackoverflow/commit/6679e5eb2b0f2a5d8fc4750bcaff201afc058a1c

And the corresponding [green Travis CI build](https://travis-ci.org/mle-enso/stackoverflow/builds/520463905).

Comment: Thanks @mle, I tried using RelaxedHTTPSValidation, but now i am getting the error as
RSA premaster secret error
there is no key for this request.

Comment: Strange, I've never encountered this one. Please add the corresponding stack trace into your question. Please add also your Java version and the versions for the relevant dependencies such as RESTAssured.

Comment: I am using jdk1.8 and rest assured 2.9.0
and below is the console error:-

Comment: The method which shows your RestAssured call `getServiceResponse` does not appear in the stack trace. Are you sure, this is the right one? And by the way, which OS are you using, Mac OS X?

Comment: I am using windows 7. the method name is getSpreadSheet(), i have updated the same in query

Comment: Sorry for the many questions but what exact JDK version, which update? Could you also, if not already happened, update to the latest update – for now `8u201` and give it a try?

Comment: I've just tested your code successfully with Java 11 and could provide a running example project if you wished. Even with relaxed HTTPS validation, everything runs fine for me, and I get a HTTP 403, but no exception, especially no SSL-relevant one.

Comment: The jdk version is jdk1.8.0_191. can you please provide me with the snippet what you are executing.

Comment: Thanks, the issue has been resolved, after executing in jdk8u201.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the SSL certificate issue, make sure you have placed appropriate certificates in the jdk1.8.0_192\jre\lib\security.